# Return value of low-level calls not used

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have an error in my code. Can I have some help please?

The code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;

/* The token is used as a voting shares */
contract token { mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;  }

/* The democracy contract itself */

contract Democracy {

/* Contract Variables and events */
uint public minimumQuorum;
uint public debatingPeriodInMinutes;
Proposal[] public proposals;
uint public numProposals;
token public sharesTokenAddress;

event ProposalAdded(uint proposalID, address recipient, uint amount, string description);
event Voted(uint proposalID, bool position, address voter);
event ProposalTallied(uint proposalID, int result, uint quorum, bool active);

struct Proposal {
    address recipient;
    uint amount;
    string description;
    uint votingDeadline;
    bool openToVote;
    bool proposalPassed;
    uint numberOfVotes;
    bytes32 proposalHash;
    Vote[] votes;
    mapping (address => bool) voted;
}

struct Vote {
    bool inSupport;
    address voter;
}

/* modifier that allows only shareholders to vote and create new proposals */
modifier onlyShareholders {
    if (sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender) == 0) throw;
    _;
}

/* First time setup */
function Democracy(token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesForVoting, uint minutesForDebate) {
    sharesTokenAddress = token(sharesAddress);
    if (minimumSharesForVoting == 0 ) minimumSharesForVoting = 1;
    minimumQuorum = minimumSharesForVoting;
    debatingPeriodInMinutes = minutesForDebate;
}

/* Function to create a new proposal */
function newProposal(address beneficiary, uint etherAmount, string JobDescription, bytes transactionBytecode) onlyShareholders returns (uint proposalID) {
    proposalID = proposals.length++;
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalID];
    p.recipient = beneficiary;
    p.amount = etherAmount;
    p.description = JobDescription;
    p.proposalHash = sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
    p.votingDeadline = now + debatingPeriodInMinutes * 1 minutes;
    p.openToVote = true;
    p.proposalPassed = false;
    p.numberOfVotes = 0;
    ProposalAdded(proposalID, beneficiary, etherAmount, JobDescription);
    numProposals = proposalID+1;
}

/* function to check if a proposal code matches */
function checkProposalCode(uint proposalNumber, address beneficiary, uint etherAmount, bytes transactionBytecode) constant returns (bool codeChecksOut) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    return p.proposalHash == sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
}

/* */
function vote(uint proposalNumber, bool supportsProposal) onlyShareholders returns (uint voteID){
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    if (p.voted[msg.sender] == true) throw;

    voteID = p.votes.length++;
    p.votes[voteID] = Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender});
    p.voted[msg.sender] = true;
    p.numberOfVotes = voteID +1;
    Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender);
}

function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) returns (int result) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    /* Check if the proposal can be executed */
    if (now < p.votingDeadline  /* has the voting deadline arrived? */ 
        || !p.openToVote        /* has it been already executed? */
        ||  p.proposalHash != sha3(p.recipient, p.amount, transactionBytecode)) /* Does the transaction code match the proposal? */
        throw;

    /* tally the votes */
    uint quorum = 0;
    uint yea = 0; 
    uint nay = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
        Vote v = p.votes[i];
        uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter); 
        quorum += voteWeight;
        if (v.inSupport) {
            yea += voteWeight;
        } else {
            nay += voteWeight;
        }
    }
    /* execute result */
    if (quorum > minimumQuorum && yea > nay ) {
        // has quorum and was approved
        p.recipient.call.value(p.amount*1000000000000000000)(transactionBytecode);
        p.openToVote = false;
        p.proposalPassed = true;
    } else if (quorum > minimumQuorum && nay > yea) {
        p.openToVote = false;
        p.proposalPassed = false;
    } 
    /* Fire Events */
    ProposalTallied(proposalNumber, result, quorum, p.openToVote);
}
}
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little too much to wade through and fully sort out for you, but here is the general idea.

```
    if(p.recipient.call.value(p.amount*1000000000000000000)(transactionBytecode)) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
```

The error is saying that there is an expected return value and your code seems to be (is) ignoring it.

Basically, it's warning you about  a possible oversight in the contract.

`// do something`, and `// do something else` are obviously placeholders. A word of caution: It's important to structure things so they do what you want *and* provide re-entrance protection. A general pattern for this is:

1. Optimistic accounting. Ensure a completely resolved contract state.
2. Try the send/untrusted function & check the result.
3. Revert Optimistic account (possibly with throw) if necessary. Log events.

So, you can do (pseudo):

```
balance[x] += amount; 
if(!user.send(amount)) throw;
LogSent(user, amount);
```

Optimistic accounting first means balance[x] is already adjusted in the case the called contract loops around and calls another function in this contract.

As well as resolving the immediate issue the compiler is warning about, restructure it so there are no state changes after:

```
if(p.recipient.call.value(p.amount*1000000000000000000)(transactionBytecode))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - Read with caution:**

[Rob's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13216/52) probably makes more sense. What worries me about my answer is why the warning (the OP's error) disappears when the compiler version is changed...

---

With this code in [Browser Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) I get:

1. An error, telling me the code requires a newer version of the compiler;
2. Your error, but in the form of a warning (presumably because the real error is the compiler version).

So the fix is to change the first line to:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.10;
```

It might be better for you to use Browser Solidity in the short term. I'm not sure why the Wallet isn't outputting the compiler version error.

Comment: https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/04/ethereum-in-practice-part-2-how-to-build-a-better-democracy-in-under-a-100-lines-of-code/

Comment: Interesting. So it's code from an official tutorial, in which case the fix would seem to be just to change the compiler version, like I said. The tutorial is very old (2015), and lots of things have changed since then, including certain aspects of Solidity.