# msg value get low level call error

Tags: contract-debugging

```
 function enter() payable {
     if (msg.value < 10 finney) {
         msg.sender.send(msg.value);
         return;
     }
```

I am getting `return value from low-level calls` in Mist wallet. Solidity version: 0.4.8+commit.60cc1668 .. T_T please help. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send msg.sender's funds back if payment is too low?

The compiler issue is you're not checking true or false return value of `send()`. Success isn't assured. See here: [Return value of low-level calls not used](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/return-value-of-low-level-calls-not-used)

In the case of returning funds for invalid transactions, you can simplify the process with `throw;`

Consider:

```
function enter() public payable returns (bool success) {
  if (msg.value < 10 finney) throw;
  return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ty so much for this T_T....

Comment: hi.. i wanna report.. all goes well. ty so much again.. this is my first time going around copy and paste peoples contract and try running it... if u dont mind.. i wanna ask.. why my contract can't automatically interact when someone send ether directly to the contract? users need to write/interect with contract to be able to call function enter.