# Hi i am getting error msg.value non-payable

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, payable

I had this function

```
function enter() {
  if (msg.value >10 finney) {

  uint amount=msg.value;
  uint payout;
```

but i am getting error:

> ballot.sol:56:9: Warning: "msg.value" used in non-payable function. Do you want to add the "payable" modifier to this function?
>
> ```
> if (msg.value >10 finney) {
> ```

anyone can help me? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Superseded by the next question... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13268/msg-value-get-low-level-call-error